# "I had my hair cut by a barber." Is that sentence grammatical?

Tags: causative-have

> I had my hair cut by a barber.

Is that sentence grammatical?

Can we add the by-phrase "by a barber" to the construction *subject + have + something + done*?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I had my hair cut by a barber.

> I had my hair cut.

Both examples are grammatical.   The phrase *by a barber* can be implied.

Comment: I had my hair cut by a blind man, as you can see.